# Splitting column values by space and getting each split value in new row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have very few experience of SQL queries but I have this requirement for my project for searching and providing auto-suggestion of description.

```
Id            Description
1                 Processing Peater order
2                 Dent in front panel 
3                 New item purchased
```

if user inputs " P " in text box then

Desired result

```
Processing 
Peater
panel
purchased
```

---

Note: Each value in result set is unique.
Sorry for my English is not very good.

Comment: This is not something you should be doing in the database to begin with. Pull the entire description into your client program and do the splitting there.

Comment: is your only option to implement this in SQL ? Do you have a higher level logic that runs in .NET,php or something else ?

Comment: @MarcB you can actually do this with a stored procedure, using a technique like http://www.montrealseocompany.com/2012/04/17/mysql-split-string-into-rows-function/

Comment: I have updated my question. Yes I can do this stuff in .Net but then it might take more time, then auto-suggestion will be of no use. Thanks of primary edit @MarcB.

Comment: @nirk: yes, but look at how ugly it is. large quantities of sql, temporary tables, inserts, etc... in PHP this would be a simple `explode(' ', $description)` and a teensy bit of array fiddling to merge/unique the values.

Comment: @MarcB I'm not disagreeing with the opinion that you could do it in PHP or perl or python or whatever, but it is doable with mysql alone

Comment: why not item and in and front and ... ?

Comment: ok I have achieved the requirement through application program by fetching the limited rows of description and then splitting and matching it by user input. Thanks for help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fine thing to do in a database.  The problem is that you have the wrong data structure.  You need to create a lexicon when you load the data into the table.  The lexicon could just be a count of words.  Or, it could be basically an inverted index, with columns for:

- Word
- Id
- Position

This gives you the data structure you need for your project.

To create this data structure, I would basically run the following query over and over to fill the lexicon:

```
insert into lexicon(word, id, pos)
    select substring_index(substring_index(description, ' ', pos), ' ', -1), id, pos 
    from t cross join
         (select 1 as pos) const 
    where length(description) - length(replace(description, ' ', '')) >= pos;
```

Each time, increment the value for `pos` in the subquery.

EDIT:

This *could* be done without a new table, if you know the maximum number of words in a description.  I wouldn't recommend it.  But something like this would work:

```
    select distinct substring_index(substring_index(description, ' ', pos), ' ', -1) as word
    from t cross join
         (select 1 as pos union all
          select 2 union all
          select 3 union all
          select 4 union all
          select 5 union all
          select 6 union all
          select 7 union all
          select 8 union all
          select 9 union all
          select 10 union all
         ) const 
    where length(description) - length(replace(description, ' ', '')) >= pos
    having word like 'p%'
```